# Making a Plot legend containing both markers and lines?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am trying to make a legend comprised of both the plot's marker symbol and a line. Specifically, I am hoping to have a legend that looks like the line is crossing through the marker. My current code only shows a line:

```
Function1 = Exp[-0.03*g100];

Plot1 = Plot[Function1, {g100, 0.000001, 100}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{Style["test", FontSize -> 20,
        Black]}, {0.9, 0.85}]];
Plot2 = ListPlot[
   Thread[{Range[1/20, 1, 1/20], {0.228, 0.379, 0.433, 0.515, 0.557, 
      0.567, 0.621, 0.624, 0.637, 0.661, 0.663, 0.655, 0.613, 0.601, 
      0.578, 0.512, 0.484, 0.459, 0.399, 0.38}}], DataRange -> {0, 1},
    PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}];
Show[Plot1, Plot2]
```

Is there a solution to this problem, despite the fact that the markers are associated with a data set that is independent of Function1?

Comment: use `PlotLegends ->  Placed[LineLegend[{Style["test", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}], {0.9, 0.85}]` in `Plot[...]`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the obvious step of adding a `PlotLegends` argument to `Plot2` does what I think you are asking for

```
Function1 = Exp[-0.03*g100];

Plot1 = Plot[Function1, {g100, 0.000001, 100}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{Style["test", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, {0.9, 0.85}]];
Plot2 = ListPlot[
   Thread[{Range[1/20, 1, 1/20], {0.228, 0.379, 0.433, 0.515, 0.557, 
      0.567, 0.621, 0.624, 0.637, 0.661, 0.663, 0.655, 0.613, 0.601, 
      0.578, 0.512, 0.484, 0.459, 0.399, 0.38}}], DataRange -> {0, 1},
    PlotMarkers -> {"●", 15}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{Style["test 2", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, {0.9, 0.85}], 
   PlotRange -> {0, 0.4}];
Show[Plot1, Plot2]
```

[image]